How can I get back some windows 10 features in Windows 11?
I have somehow upgraded from Windows 10 to Windows 11 without intending to do so. I am having two problems. There were a lot of things on the Start menu you reached by clicking on the windows button in the lower left corner which can no longer be reached from there, nor from the new Windows or Start button in the middle of the bottom bar. Of these, the most important were the "all programs" menu and the windows desktop search field. The new Windows search window does not provide any obvious way to limit the search to my own machine. When I search for a program I have installed, it takes me to the vendor's web page.
How can I get back the previous (Windows 10) start menu? If there is no way to do that shorts of scrapping and reinstalling the OS, is there at least a way to:

get to an all programs menu that shows the programs I have installed?
limit searches to local files on my machine? Preferably as the default. If I want to search the web, I will use a web browser. I never want to do a combined search of my own machine and the world wide web. If there is no way to make that the default, is there any way to do it at all? Or do I have to abandon Microsoft search completely and move to Copernic?


for a limited time after the upgrade to win 11, it is possible to downgrade to windows 10 as described here. But notice that Windows 10 is supported only until October 2025, so at some point you'll have to take the step

In the start menu there is a "All apps" button which navigates you to a searchable list of all installed applications.


To disable web search, open the group policy editor gpedit.msc, navigate to Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Search, and enable

Do not allow web search
Don't allow search the web or display web search results in Search
Don't allow search the web or display web search results in Search over metered connections

